# Prove that $x^4 + 131 = 3y^4$ has no integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

So I came across this problem in a book. I figured a few steps out but I am not sure if it is correct.

x<sup>4</sup> + 131 = 3y<sup>4</sup>
x<sup>4</sup> + 2 = 3y<sup>4</sup> - 129
x<sup>4</sup> + 2 = 3(y<sup>4</sup> - 43)
x<sup>4</sup> + 2 ≡ 0 (mod 3)
x<sup>4</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 3)

Let x<sup>4</sup> = 3k + 1,
y<sup>4</sup> = k + 44

I have no idea what to do next, or how to find a contradiction.

Comment: Wow yes thanks, to think that someone actually posted an exact same question.

Comment: This site is 11 years old and has 1m+ questions after all... . FYI, I find that question using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/). If you know how to type mathematical expression using latex (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)), you can search this site very easily.